# How to append data on change event of one select to second select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select drop downs in same table row.
I want to add data to second drop down on change of first drop down.
Both drop downs do not have id or class??
is it possible without id or class append data to it??

Here is my html..

```
<button type="button"  id = "add-row" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add new
</button>
<table class="table" id="mans">
<tr>
<td><select class="form-control tag-list-name">
       <option>ABC</option>
       <option>PQR</option>
   </select>
</td>
<td><select class="form-control">
    <option> </option>
   </select></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right delete-row">
         -
   </button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What data do you want to add? And what have you tried so far? It will be a lot easier if you add a unique class or ID to both dropdowns..

Comment: I want to add dynamic data which I get through ajax response. e.g. <option>Add1</option>

Comment: You'll need to show some code indicating what effort you've made and how it's failing.

Comment: Yeah we will need some more code in order to help you.

Comment: To select just the first one you can use `$('tr select:eq(0)').on('change', function() whatever you want here to select the 2nd ($(this).parents('tr').get(0)).find('tr select:eq(1)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using following code :

Added new class name to second select/drop down.

And then used following code:

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var select = tr.find('.tag-name-values');
var currentContext = select.html("");
currentContext.append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.first()` and `.eq()` to select them.

```
var selects = $('#mans select');

selects.first().on('change', function () {
    selects.eq(1).append('<option>New Option</option>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nE9G3/2/)

Comment: Yes ur are right. but I have multiple select on same page as rows are dynamically added.
But only two on same row(tr) in table. Do I set value of second similarly

Comment: @user3322141 This will only select the first and last select within an element with an id of `mans`.

Comment: More than the two from your HTML snippet?

Comment: Actually I have a button to add select dropdown. Each time when it get clicked add a duplicate of last row to table. And I want to change value of second drop down on change of first in each row of table